# Browser compatibility submitting form data to PHP file using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I'm sending form data to a PHP file using the Ajax code below (that I found at this website) so the results returned by the PHP file remain on the same page.  Works great if using Firefox.  Other browsers are not working which is why I added the "else" portion to use another method of submitting the form data if using a browser other than Firefox.  This works, but the results end up on a new page.

Any way I can do this so that after detecting a browser other than Firefox I can get the same results but stay on the same page?

```
if(browserInfo.indexOf("Firefox") > -1) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Don't reload page on form Submit
  var form_data = $(this).serializeObject();
  // Send the value to the server
  $.ajax({
    url: "MyTest.php",
    type: "post",
    data: form_data,
    success: function(result) {
      $("div#result_box").html(result)
    }
  });
}
else {
  document.getElementById("my_form").submit();  
}
```

Comment: A semicolon is missing after `$("div#result_box").html(result)`. It can be an error on some browers and so, your code won't work.

Comment: How do you cause this code to run?

Comment: Added the semicolon.  Surprised it was even working in Firefox without it.  But even with the semicolon, other browsers will still not work without the "else" statement which prints the results on a new page.

Comment: Doing more research on this site, I got it working by adding an iFrame to my initial html file, leaving the code above as is.  I added target="myIframe" to my form description.  Not exactly sure why that prevents the PHP file from displaying a new page, but I'll quit while I'm ahead.